# How to overlay two wav files with C# and NAudio?

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I am using the NAudio library to work on audio files. What I want to do is to put together multiple audios and combine them from the starting point. If I need to explain with a figure;

```
A.wav
|-------------------------|
B.wav
|---------------|
```

I wrote the codes below for this process, but this code combines the voices in the following way;

```
A.wav |--------------------| B.wav |--------------|
```

Here is the code block;

```
public static void Concatenate(string outputFile, IEnumerable<string> sourceFiles)
        {
            outputFile = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\umutg\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Muesyco\Combined\" + outputFile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            WaveFileWriter waveFileWriter = null;

            try
            {
                foreach (string sourceFile in sourceFiles)
                {
                    using (WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader(sourceFile))
                    {
                        if (waveFileWriter == null)
                        {
                            // first time in create new Writer
                            waveFileWriter = new WaveFileWriter(outputFile, reader.WaveFormat);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (!reader.WaveFormat.Equals(waveFileWriter.WaveFormat))
                            {
                                throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't concatenate WAV Files that don't share the same format");
                            }
                        }

                        int read;
                        while ((read = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            waveFileWriter.WriteData(buffer, 0, read);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (waveFileWriter != null)
                {
                    waveFileWriter.Dispose();
                }
            }

        }
```

**Edit**

```
public static string CreateMashup(List<string> files, string filename)
{
    List<AudioFileReader> mixList = new List<AudioFileReader>();
    // because there is no mash up with less than 2 files
    if (files.Count() < 2)
    {
        throw new Exception("Not enough files selected!");
    }

    try
    {
        var mixer = new WaveMixerStream32
        {
            AutoStop = true
        };

        var outputFile = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\umutg\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Muesyco\Combined\" + filename);

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var filePath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\umutg\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Muesyco\Download\" + file);

            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                var reader = new AudioFileReader(filePath);
                mixList.Add(reader);
            }
        }

        var _mixer = new MixingSampleProvider(mixList);
        WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16(outputFile, _mixer);

        return outputFile;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // TODO: handle exception
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Found what you are looking for in their Documentation
>   [Here](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/MixTwoAudioFilesToWav.md)

**Update:**
Have you take a look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098048/how-to-mix-2-wav-files-together)

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried that but it makes A.wav |--------------------| B.wav |--------------|. I added the code I used.

Comment: @UmutGür check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098048/how-to-mix-2-wav-files-together is this what you are looking for?