# How do I merge two wave files into one in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, opentk, openal, wave

I need to merge two wave files in .net core. So I choosed OpenTK as wrapper for OpenAL.

I tried to merge two wave files with same bits per sample and sapmle rate.

1) To do this I get this [example](https://github.com/mono/opentk/blob/master/Source/Examples/OpenAL/1.1/Playback.cs)

2) Make 2 byte areas:

```
var sound_data1 = LoadWave(path1, FileMode.Open), out channels, out bits_per_sample, out sample_rate);

var sound_data2 = LoadWave(path2, FileMode.Open), out channels, out bits_per_sample, out sample_rate);
```

3) Make sum for each byte and devide it to 2

```
for (int i = 0; i < sound_data1; i++)
{
result_sound_data[i] = (byte)((sound_data1[i] + sound_data2[i]) / 2);
}
```

4) then:

```
AL.BufferData(buffer, GetSoundFormat(channels, bits_per_sample), result_sound_data, result_sound_data.Length, sample_rate);

AL.Source(source, ALSourcei.Buffer, buffer);
AL.SourcePlay(source);
```

An finaly I got some damaged sound instead of mixed signal. How do I solve it?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35725/C-WAV-file-class-audio-mixing-and-some-light-audio) help?

Comment: I use .net core, so can't use .net classes like WAVFile

Comment: You can't apply simple arithmetic to sound samples. E.g.: Dividing by 2 introduces __an error for all odd numbers__. You need to understand about __error dithering__ or the errors will create nasty __artifacts__. So you need a library or some really clever workarounds.

Comment: Imagine that the values are actually 16 bits. Sample one has a value of 30000 and sample two has a value of 20000. The average of these should be 25000. However if you treat these as bytes then the average will come out completely wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Mix 2 wav files together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098048/how-to-mix-2-wav-files-together)  Pay particular attention to Thomas Weller's answer.

Comment: @lan it's good observation, but I need to use .net core, so I can't use libraries for .net like naudio

Comment: Did you even *look* at that codeproject sample? Nothing in the code is .net framework specific. I just tried, and the code (WAVFile, WAVFormat, WAVFileException) compiles just fine on .net core.

Comment: @jeroenh thanks, I mistook this example with another one that uses naudio. So you can make an answer.

Comment: @MatthewWatson you can alse make an answer. Maybe you can give me advice how to properly calculate and get average sample?

Comment: @MatthewWatson your comment helped to solve it, you can post an answer

Comment: @jeroenh your answer helps to solve it as well, you can post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging audio streams is apparently basically taking a sum of the corresponding samples in each input audio file. You can study the source code of [this sample on codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35725/C-WAV-file-class-audio-mixing-and-some-light-audio). This code is maybe not the cleanest, but seems to do the job (I tested).

Apart from handling the WAV file header, the actual merging logic for an array of input files is described here:

```
// 8. Do the merging..
// The basic algorithm for doing the merging is as follows:
// while there is at least 1 sample remaining in any of the source files
//    sample = 0
//    for each source file
//       if the source file has any samples remaining
//          sample = sample + next available sample from the source file
//    sample = sample / # of source files
//    write the sample to the output file
```

This is implemented in that code sample as follows, for 8-bit samples:

```
while (SamplesRemain(scaledAudioFiles))
{
    byte sample = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < scaledAudioFiles.GetLength(0); ++i)
    {
        if (scaledAudioFiles[i].NumSamplesRemaining > 0)
        {
            sample += scaledAudioFiles[i].GetNextSample_8bit();
        }
    }
    sample /= (byte)(scaledAudioFiles.GetLength(0));
    outputFile.AddSample_8bit(sample);
}
```

The code in that sample is entirely compatible with .Net Core.

If you just want to take that code and merge some .wav files, here's how to do just that (still, using the sample in question):

```
    private static void Main(string[] args) => WAVFile.MergeAudioFiles(
            new[] { "file1.wav", "file2.wav", "file3.wav" },
            "result.wav",
            Path.GetTempPath()
        );
```